# How to convert ZIP to GZIP in python, in-memory (AWS Lambda)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, compression, gzip, ram

I have managed to convert zip files to gzip, using AWS lambda's local storage `/tmp`. The problem is that this storage maxes out at 500Mb.

```
def zip_to_gzip(zip):

    # Unzip <filename>.zip
    zfile = ZipFile(zip)
    filename = zfile.namelist()[0]
    data = zfile.read(filename)
    f = open('/tmp/' + str(filename), 'wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()

    # Compress <filename>.gzip
    gzip_file = gzip.open(
        f'/tmp/{filename}.gz', 'wb')
    gzip_file.write(data)
    gzip_file.close()
```

I would like to do this, exclusively in RAM, without using any local storage/hard drive.

Any ideas how? The `io` module doesn't seem to be appropriate for this use (I am not 100% sure about that though)

Comment: `io.StringIO` seems like it should be perfect for this.

Comment: By the way, if execution time is important to you, there is a better way to do this. The data in that first zip file entry is almost certainly compressed using the deflate format. If so, it does not need to be decompressed and recompressed. You don't even need to calculate the CRC-32 or uncompressed length, since those are already there as well. You just need to strip the zip headers and trailers and subsequent entries, and replace them with a gzip header and trailer. It would take a little work to interpret the zip format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do as you ask:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gzip

# Make 10kB of compressible zeroes of data
data = bytearray(10240)

outfilename = 'sample.gz'
with gzip.open(outfilename, 'wb') as output:
     output.write(data)
```

Adapted from Doug Hellman's excellent [PYMOTW](https://pymotw.com/3/gzip/index.html).

**Check results**

```
# The size is 52 bytes:
ls -l sample.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  52  7 Feb 17:51 sample.gz

# The type is correct
file -b --mime  sample.gz
application/gzip; charset=binary

# It decompresses to the correct size 
gunzip < sample.gz | wc -c
10240
```